# How to get a nested field

Tags: java, reflection

I'm new of reflection and I'm trying to get a nested field. Summarizing I have the following classes:

```
public class Agreement{

    private Long id;

    private String cdAgreement;

    private Address address;

    //Constructor getter and setter

}

public class Address{

    private Long id;

    private String description;

    //Constructor getter and setter

}
```

Now I want to get the description field, then i wrote this code:

```
Agreement agreement = new Agreement();
Class c = agreement.getClass();
Field f = c.getDeclaredField("address.descritpion");
```

but not works, I get the following exception:

```
java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: address.descritpion
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredField(Class.java:1948)
```

Where am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The current problem is that no field has the name "address.description" (it's not even a valid name for a field).

You have to get the address field first, access its class, and get the nested field from there. To do so, use `getType()`:

```
Agreement agreement = new Agreement();
Class c = agreement.getClass();          // Agreement class
Field f = c.getDeclaredField("address"); // address field
Class<?> fieldClass = f.getType();       // class of address field (Address)
Field nested = fieldClass.getDeclaredField("description"); // description field
```

You can also chain the calls without local variables:

```
Field nested = c.getDeclaredField("address").getType().getDeclaredField("description");
```

Answer (score 0):

you must decompose operations.

```
Agreement agreement = new Agreement();
Field fAddress = agreement.getClass().getDeclaredField("address");
Address address = (Address)fAddress.get(agreement);
Field fDescription = address.getClass().getDeclaredField("description");
String description = (String)fDescription.get(address);
```

Comment: You don't need to get the value of the field, just its Class. Moreover, this could throw NPE when calling `getClass()`.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. Too hasty. Your answer is right.